# Is there a way to drain durability from an item instead of a sword, for instance?

Tags: minecraft-modding, modding

I am modding Minecraft 1.8 using Eclipse with Forge, and I just wondered, is there a way to drain durability from a battery, for instance, instead of a piece of armor when hit. 
I have tried things like getting an item from the player's inventory and attempting to reduce its durability, so that would be a possibility, however, I was unable to find a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the field `inventory` in the player class to help you. Using the method `player.inventory.hasItemStack(ItemStack);` to test if it contains the battery item.
An example:

```
@Override
public boolean onLeftClickEntity(ItemStack stack, EntityPlayer player,
        Entity entity) {
  if (player.inventory.hasItemStack(Items.battery)) {
    //Do something to it
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```